# ERROR: Arithmetic: `b/0' is not a function

Tags: prolog

I need to find out what's the element in a specified list index. Here is my code:

```
% [1]
mylist_element_at([], _, _) :- fail.

% [2]
mylist_element_at(L, N, _) :-
    length(L, S),
    N > S,
    fail.

% [3]
mylist_element_at(L, N, X) :-
    mylist_element_at(L, 1, N, X).    

% [4.1]
mylist_element_at([H | _], C, N, X) :- 
    C == N,
    X is H, !.

% [4.2]
% mylist_element_at([H | _], N, N, H) :- !.

% [5]
mylist_element_at([_ | T], C, N, X) :-
    C < N,
    CI is C + 1,
    mylist_element_at(T, CI, N, X).
```

```
?- mylist_element_at([a,b,c],2,X).
```

But [4.1] is giving me this error:

```
ERROR: Arithmetic: `b/0' is not a function
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [13] _18060 is b
ERROR:   [12] mylist_element_at([b,c],2,2,_18092) at /Users/mahmudulhaque/IdeaProjects/prolog/asg03.prolog:65
ERROR:   [11] mylist_element_at([a,b|...],1,2,_18134) at /Users/mahmudulhaque/IdeaProjects/prolog/asg03.prolog:72
ERROR:   [10] mylist_element_at([a,b|...],2,_18174) at /Users/mahmudulhaque/IdeaProjects/prolog/asg03.prolog:61
ERROR:    [9] toplevel_call(user:user: ...) at /usr/local/Cellar/swi-prolog/8.4.1/libexec/lib/swipl/boot/toplevel.pl:1117
   Exception: (13) _3226 is b ? creep
   Exception: (12) mylist_element_at([b, c], 2, 2, _3226) ?
```

```
?- help(is).
-Number is +Expr
```

So, in [5] `C + 1` is an Expr and `CI` is unbound. So, `CI` unifies with `C + 1`. Shouldn't it be the same case for [4.1]. `X` is unbound and `H` is an Expr. So, `X` should unifies with `H`! Using `=` or [4.2] fixes the issue. What am I missing for `is`?

Comment: `X is H` is the culprit. Use `X = H`. There is more to this.

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged [swi-prolog](/questions/tagged/swi-prolog), why not just use [nth0\3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=nth0/3) or [nth1\3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=nth1/3) provided by SWI Prolog?

```
?- nth0(1, [a,b,c], X).
X = b.
```

Answer (score 0):

> So, in [5] C + 1 is an Expr and CI is unbound. So, CI unifies with C + 1.

No. `CI` unifies with *the value of `C + 1` interpreted as an arithmetic expression*. If `C` is 4, `CI is C + 1` will unify `CI` with 5. If you want to unify `CI` with the *term* `C + 1`, you would write `CI = C + 1`. Then `CI` will unify with the term `4 + 1`. That term is not the same as the term `5`.

> X is unbound and H is an Expr. So, X should unifies with H!

But here `H` is `b`, which is not an arithmetic expression. It makes no sense to apply `is` to it because `is` wants arithmetic expressions. If you want `X` to *unify with the term `H`*, use the unification operator: `=`.